# Request Node Module Variable Scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

This has been getting to me for a while. So, I am trying to create a function that uses request and returns *body* of the request, using the request node module. Here is my code:

```
req = require("request")
foo = req("https://www.youtube.com", function(err, resp, body){
    bar = body
})
console.log(bar)
```

This, sadly, returns `ReferenceError: bar is not defined`
Anyone able to help? Please test your answer before you post it, because I have tried almost *EVERYTHING* I can think of.

Comment: you have to initialize every variable with `var`:
`var bar;`
`var foo = ... { bar = body }`
`console.log(bar);`

Comment: logging `bar` outside the `req` function will return nothing especially considering bar has not been defined. Do you get the same result when log `bar` after `bar = body;`?

Comment: but you have asynchronous call, so `console.log(bar)` anyway prints 'undefined'

Comment: Slavik: I already tried that. AVDW: It works, but that is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var request = require("request")
request("https://www.youtube.com", function(err, resp, body){
    bar = body;
    console.log(bar);
});
```

Comment: I am trying to make a function that returns the value bar. For this, that would not work because you cannot specify a return value for the containing function in a function

Comment: I got it.  NO more answers required.

Comment: great, if you got clue how async works and how you could get it working the please mark asnwer correct

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse it well return `ReferenceError: bar is not defined` because `bar` it define only inide the `req` and also your `console.log` should be inside the `req`

```
req = require("request")
foo = req("https://www.youtube.com", function(err, resp, body){
    var bar = body;
    console.log(bar);
})
```

Comment: I know why, I just do not know how to do it. Also, the code above will be in a function that returns the value bar.